# A more elegant way of selecting and inserting from 2 tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables like:

```
ID NAME
-------------
1  someValue
2  someValue
3  someValue
4  someValue
...


ID NAME
-------------
1  var
2  var2
3  var3
4  var4
...
```

I want to insert in a `@table`  2 results from table1, and, 3 results from table2, with different ID, Currently I have something like:

```
Declare @vars TABLE(
        field1  varchar(80),
        field2  varchar(80),
        field3  varchar(80),
        field4  varchar(80),
        field5  varchar(80)
    )

INSERT INTO @vars(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
    SELECT  a.Name,
            b.Name,
            c.Name,
            d.Name,
            e.Name
    FROM    @Table1  a,
            @Table1  b, 
            @Table2  c,
            @Table2  d,
            @Table2  e
    WHERE   a.ID = 1 
    AND     b.ID = 25
    AND     c.ID = 12 
    AND     d.ID = 25 
    AND     e.ID = 14
```

I get the expected values, but...

- Is there a more elegant way to do
  this? I guess I´m doing more than 
  needed.

P.D.
I get something like:

```
field1  field2 field3 field4 field5
-------------------------------------
val1     var2    val4   val7   var7
```

Comment: Using the `table1, table2, table3, .....` old-style JOIN syntax, you're bound to have cartesian products, if you don't pay a lot of attention! I would recommend always using the new, standardized ANSI JOIN syntax instead : `INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If ID is a primary key or unique key in Table1 and Table 2 you can do this instead.

```
insert into @vars
select
  (select Name from @Table1 where ID = 1),
  (select Name from @Table1 where ID = 25),
  (select Name from @Table2 where ID = 12),
  (select Name from @Table2 where ID = 25),
  (select Name from @Table2 where ID = 14)
```

Comment: Hey, that's not fair! I was going to post a solution that was only slightly more elegant than the OP's. Yours should have been posted afterwards to outshine all of them! :) +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's more elegant, but here's a different query that does the same.

```
WITH myTables AS
    ( SELECT ID, NAME, 'Table1' AS SOURCE
    FROM Table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ID, NAME, 'Table2' AS SOURCE
    FROM Table2
    )
INSERT INTO @vars(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN source = 'Table1' AND id = 1  THEN NAME END) AS field1,
    MAX(CASE    WHEN source = 'Table1' AND id = 25 THEN NAME END) AS field2,
    MAX(CASE    WHEN source = 'Table2' AND id = 12 THEN NAME END) AS field3,
    MAX(CASE    WHEN source = 'Table2' AND id = 25 THEN NAME END) AS field4,
    MAX(CASE    WHEN source = 'Table2' AND id = 14 THEN NAME END) AS field5
FROM myTables
WHERE SOURCE = ('Table1'  AND ID IN (1, 25))
    OR (SOURCE = 'Table2' AND ID IN (12, 25, 14)) ;
```

It uses a common table expression (CTE) to create a union of the two tables.  It also pivots the data using the MAX aggregation.  You can also do this with the PIVOT operator.